# Vue dynamic route transition (based on from/to) not being applied

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, transition, vue-router

I'm having trouble implementing a certain page transition.

In my app there is a neutral state (no routes activated). I have two routes leading to the (same) Page component, displaying content based on the route props.

I want the transition from the neutral state to a page (or vice versa) to change the opacity (appearing / disappearing). From page to page it should slide from left to right.

I'm watching $route to achieve this, as described in the documentation (https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/transitions.html#route-based-dynamic-transition).

Please have a look at my example: https://codesandbox.io/s/n06mojkv7j

Clicking 'A' or 'B' takes you to the corresponding page. Clicking 'X' brings you back to the neutral state.

So, in neutral state clicking 'A' changes the opacity from 0 to 1. Clicking 'X' changes the opacity from 1 to 0. So far so good.

When Page A is active, clicking 'B' slides the pages horizontally. Also as intended.

However when you've come from neutral, clicking A, then B (all transitions have been as intended), clicking 'X' is where it goes wrong. You'll see the page sliding horizontally as opposed to the opacity going from 1 to 0 (which is the intended use for coming from or going to the neutral state).

The conditions in the $route watcher have been met, the transitionName actually is changed to 'opacity' (as you can also see in the console output). But the wrong transition is being applied.

I hope you guys can give me any insights into the problem :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adds a configuration for route.path='/' like below then will fix the issue you met.

Or you can look into [one working demo at CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1yw20w3mpq)

The demo:

```
const routes = [
  {
    name: "/",
    path: "/",
    component: {template:'<div/>'}
  },
  {
    name: "A",
    path: "/a",
    component: Page,
    props: { text: "A" }
  },
  {
    name: "B",
    path: "/B",
    component: Page,
    props: { text: "B" }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue! Any idea why you would need to explicitly add a route for it? I guess it makes sense because it is a different path, therefor a different route, but it doesn't explain why the correct transition isn't applied; after all the transitionName does update correctly.

Comment: I suspected it is caused by [the cache mechanism](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/src/components/view.js#L41) of Vue router,